# Pandas dataframe.read_csv with a comma in the column reads incorectly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read a csv file with the following values `[23, " 5,000.00 ", A]`

I need to read the number with a comma, but I'm not able to do it even if I pass a decimal and a quotechar.

I'm reading a CSV that `df.read_csv(path, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', decimal=',', thousands='.', dtype=str)`

I'm getting the following output if I run `df.values.tolist()`
=> `['23', ' " 5', '000.00 "', 'A']`

What might be the problem?

The column with this type of data is always different. So I cannot transform it based on column name.
`dtype=str` should be left as a string, as it's necessary for the future.

Comment: Are you opening this CSV in Excel?

Comment: @BigBen After writing to the CSV I open it in text editor or Excel. The output is the same

Comment: Try specifying the `quotechar`  and `decimal` parameters for `df.read_csv`: dataframe.to_csv(buffer, delimiter=",",  quotechar='"', decimal=",", encoding="utf-8", index=False)

Comment: @ibmx Just checked. It didn't work. Still the same output

Comment: Another thing you can try is to change the delimiter to something else, like `"|"` or `";"`.

Comment: I noticed that probably it's the problem with reading it. I'm going to update the question

Comment: @ibmx thank you for suggesting it. It didn't help. Still getting `['23', ' " 5', '000.00 "', 'A']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set skipinitialspace's value.

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=',', quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
print(result.columns)
```

And my data.csv looks like this:
23; " 5,000.0 "; A

Running the code above give this result:
Index([u'23', u' 5,000.0 ', u'A'], dtype='object')

skipinitialspace will remove strip off the extra spaces from " 5,000.0 ".
If you try to remove the extra spaces by hand, then you can leave out this parameter and it will work just fine as well.